# Como adicionar elementos em um array

Tags: php, json

Fala pessoal, tenho certeza que é uma dúvida muito simples, mas não estou sabendo fazer.

Primeiro cenário - Tenho o seguinte array:

```
$century = array(
    'decade' => array(
        array(
            'year' => '2017',
            'months' => array(
                array('value' => 'Jan'),
            )
        )
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($century));
echo "</pre>";
```

> {"decade":[{"year":"2017","months":[{"value":"Jan"}]}]}

Até ai tudo bem, o formato está como desejo, mas alterando a forma como crio esse array e atribuo valores, tb muda a saída para um formato indesejado, veja a seguir.

---

Segundo Cenário - Formato indesejado:

```
$m = array(
    array('value' => 'Jan')
);

$century = array(
    'decade' => array()
);

$century['decade'][]['year'] = '2017';
$century['decade'][]['months'] = $m[0]['value'];


echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($century));
echo "</pre>";
```

> {"decade":[{"year":"2017"},{"months":"Jan"}]}

Percebam que agora o "year" está envolvido por '{}' individualmente e não como um todo como no primeiro cenário.

A questão é, obviamente tem uma forma certa de se fazer o segundo cenário para retornar uma saída igual a do primeiro, mas qual?

Answer (score 3):

Esse comportamento é devido à utilização do operador `[]` em sua variável `$century['decade']`. Sempre que utilizar este operador, o PHP criará um novo elemento no array em questão, ou seja, fazer:

```
$century['decade'][]['year'] = '2017';
$century['decade'][]['months'] = $m[0]['value'];
```

Criará um novo elemento ao adicionar o ano e criará um novo elemento quando adicionar os meses. Por isso sua saída possui dois elementos ao invés de um, como era esperado.

Para contornar isso de forma simples, basta criar o array antes de fazer as atribuições, como mostrado abaixo:

```
$m = array(
    array('value' => 'Jan')
);

$century = array(
    'decade' => array()
);

// Aqui é criado um array único, atribuindo corretamente os valores:
$array = array(
    'year' => '2017',
    'months' =>  $m[0]['value']
);

// Insere o novo array na variável $century['decade']:
$century['decade'][] = $array;

print_r(json_encode($century));
```

Veja o código funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/b4p0qC).

Comment: Tentei reescrever sua resposta de uma maneira mais clara. Ao meu ver, havia muita repetição em um parágrafo, o que dificultava a leitura. Se achar que não faz jus à sua resposta, sinta-se a vontade em fazer o *rollback* da edição. Aproveitei e adicionei o seu exemplo no Ideone. Espero que não se incomode.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e entendi sua explicação, mas e se eu precisar iterar sobre o array os outros meses, exemplo: (Fevereiro, março, abril.. etc)?